# Does Django have an equivalent of Rails's "bundle install"?

Tags: python, django

One thing I like about Rails projects is that when deploying to a remote server, if everything is set up correctly you can just do:

```
$: bundle install
```

And the system will install the various dependencies (ruby gems) needed to run the project.

Is there something similar for Python/Django?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can freeze requirements. This generates a list of all the Python modules that your project needs. I believe `bundle` is similar in concept.

For example:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages myproject_env # create a blank Python virtual environment
source myproject_env/bin/activate # activate it
(myproject_env)$ pip install django # install django into the virtual environment
(myproject_env)$ pip install other_package # etc.
...
(myproject_env)$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

The last line generates a text file will all the packages that were installed in your custom environment. You can use that file to install the same requirements on other servers:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Of course you don't need to use `pip`, you can create the requirements file by hand; it doesn't have any special syntax requirements. Just a package and (possibly) version identifier on each line. Here is a sample of a typical django project with some extra packages:

```
Django==1.4
South==0.7.4
Werkzeug==0.8.3
amqplib==1.0.2
anyjson==0.3.1
celery==2.5.1
django-celery==2.5.1
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
django-extensions==0.8
django-guardian==1.0.4
django-picklefield==0.2.0
kombu==2.1.4
psycopg2==2.4.5
python-dateutil==2.1
six==1.1.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlwt==0.7.3
```

Answer (score 4):

The closest is probably [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/), [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) and a [requirements file](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html).
With those 3 ingredients is quite easy to write a simple bootstrap scripts.

More demanding and complex is [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/). But I would only go for it if virtualenv and pip are not sufficient.

And if you extend this approach with [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/index.html) and optional [cuisine](https://github.com/sebastien/cuisine), you  already have your project deployment automated. Check out these links for more information:

- http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2010/04/22/basic-django-deployment-with-virtualenv-fabric-pip-and-rsync/
- http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/
- http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/